# Limit of a sequence when the algebraic limit theorem 'breaks down'

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

**Background**

There is the very well-known technique of computing the limit of a sequence by taking limit on both sides whenever recurrence relation arises. For example, $b_n = \frac{\alpha^n}{n!} $ for $0 < \alpha < 1$.

**Question**

But now there is this sequence such that taking limit on both sides will yield meaningless results:

> $$a_n = \frac{1}{3}a_{n-1} + \frac{2}{3}a_{n-2} \; \; \;\text{for any
> integer} \; n \geq 3, $$ and $a_1 = 0$, $a_2 = 1$.

The question is how this limit should be evaluated? (The existence of the limit is already proved by proving the sequence is a Cauchy sequence.)

**My attempt**

> It can be observed that
>
> $$ a_n - a_{n-1} = \frac{-2}{3} a_{n-1} + \frac{2}{3} a_{n-2} =
> \frac{-2}{3} (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2})$$
>
> Then the two sides are symmetrical and hence
>
> $$ a_n - a_{n-1}= (\frac{-2}{3})^{n-1}(a_1-a_0) =
>  (\frac{-2}{3})^{n-1}$$
>
> But again taking limit on both sides yields $ 0 = 0$

Comment: It's a linear recurrence, so it's possible to find an explicit formula for the solution.

Comment: Set $b_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ and you will see it is a gemeometric sequence. Thus $a_n=a_1+b_2+b_3+\cdots+b_n$ will give an explicit fornula for $a_n$, which is a summation of geometric sequance.

Answer (score 2):

$$a_n = \frac13a_{n-1} + \frac23a_{n-2}$$

The characteristic equation is $x^2-\frac13x-\frac23=0$.

$$3x^2-x-2=0$$

$$(3x+2)(x-1)=0$$

$$x=-\frac23,1$$

$$a_n = \alpha \left( -\frac23\right)^n+\beta$$

We have $a_1=0$ and $a_2=1$,

$$0=\alpha\left( -\frac23\right)+\beta$$

$$1=\alpha\left( -\frac23\right)^2+\beta$$

$$1=\alpha\left( -\frac23\right)\left( -\frac53\right)$$

$$\alpha=\frac9{10}, \beta=\frac23\alpha=\frac23\cdot\frac{9}{10}=\frac35$$

$$a_n = \frac{9}{10}\left( -\frac23\right)^n+\frac35$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = \frac35$$